The Exception "DockerProcessStartException" comes up when starting my Spring Boot Application
i built my first web application with Spring Boot and wanted to run it / test it locally but when i start my Application it throws the exception:
DockerProcessStartException: Unable to start docker process. Is docker correctly installed?

So do i have to install Docker in order to run Spring Boot Applications?
(I didnt install Docker so far, because it was not mentioned in any guide i have read)
Please be kind, i dont know what im doing.
I tried running the application in two different ways:

cmd: mvnw spring-boot:run
rightclick --> run as Java Application in Eclipse

Here is my pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.0</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.</groupId>
<artifactId>YuGiOhTournament</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>YuGiOhTournament</name>
<description>YuGiOh tournament</description>
<url/>
<licenses>
    <license/>
</licenses>
<developers>
    <developer/>
</developers>
<scm>
    <connection/>
    <developerConnection/>
    <tag/>
    <url/>
</scm>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>


there is not enough info... what is your start command? how exactly are you starting it? Usually it is not necessary to have docker to start Spring Boot App in your IDE

Thanks for the reply.
I started it two ways:

by the cmd command mvnw spring-boot:run
by rightclick --> run as java application in eclipse
Both gave me the exception


please add your pom.xml to the question

the dependency spring-boot-docker-compose auto detects docker-compose file and tries to run docker before start (see here). If you don't want that behavior, remove the dependency OR set the property to false with spring.docker.compose.enabled=false to avoid starting docker for that profile

Thank you for sticking around and helping me :)
I ve put spring-boot-docker-compose to false like you said. Now im getting a different error:
org.springframework.boot.docker.compose.core.ProcessExitException: 'docker version --format {{.Client.Version}}' failed with exit code 1.
Guess there is another dependency i have to remove?

Ok, putting it on false wasnt enough. I removed it completely out of the pom and now it worked :)  / im getting new errors that are not related to that topic. Thanks alot for your help. Ill figure out the rest by myself
